# Autofocus is not working for Radio Button in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, getelementsbyclassname, autofocus

We have a community page where the questions are populated dynamically and it includes a text box, a radio button and a picklist. We have written normal HTML for having these controls.

When we try to add auto focus for the radio button, such as shown below, the picklist tab is not working when the picklist is the first field in the page.

```
<input class="inputFocus" type="radio" aura:id="{!SCHOOLQUESTIONS.Id}" onchange="{!c.fireMyApplicationEvent}"  name="{!v.SCHOOLQUESTIONS.Id}" id="{!optionVals.Acc_Ques_Picklist_Name__c}" aria-describedby="{!v.SCHOOLQUESTIONS.Id}" value="{!optionVals.Acc_Ques_Picklist_Name__c}" required="Required" />
```

Javascript:

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName('inputFocus')[0]!=null) {

                    console.log('Done Rendering Called::5'+(document.getElementsByClassName('inputFocus')[0].id));
                    document.getElementsByClassName('inputFocus')[0].focus();
                    component.set("v.focusSetOnField",true);

                }
```

When we try to remove it, it is working fine. Sometimes we may have a radio button being the first field and we may want to have autofocus. Please, advise me.

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: Can you please email me at asha19990@gmail.com. I can share you the code.